# create Update Actions for pivot table attribute on laravel nova belongsToMany Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-models

I have model looks like this folowing `Product` model code:

```
public class Product extends Model
{
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class)
            ->withPivot('published');
    }
}
```

and here the `Types` model:

```
public class Type extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->withPivot('published');
    }
}
```

in nova `ProjectResource` I have this following field :

```
BelongsToMany::make('Types')
    ->fields(function() {
        return [
            Boolean::make('Published')
        ];
     })->actions(function() { return new Action/UpdateProductTypeActions }),
```

in nova `TypeResource` I have this following field :

```
BelongsToMany::make('Projects')
        ->fields(function() {
            return [
                Boolean::make('Published')
            ];
         }),
```

and I wanna make this `published`  attribute from pivot table updateable using `Nova Actions`

and I already create `UpdateProductTypeActions` like this following code:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {

        }
    }
```

my questions how to get `product_id` from those actions?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all products that have many-to-many relations with types which have many-to-many relations with $model that here is your project:

```
 foreach($model->types as $type)
   {
     $products=$type->products->pluck(id);
   }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: But what if you try publish ony one or several products (not all of them)? How you can get them?